# Finding normal vector to iOS device

Tags: ios, gyroscope, core-motion

I would like to use CMAttitude to know the vector normal to the glass of the iPad/iPhone's screen (relative to the ground). As such, I would get vectors like the following:

[image]

Notice that this is different from orientation, in that I don't care how the device is rotated about the z axis. So if I was holding the iPad above my head facing down, it would read (0,-1,0), and even as I spun it around above my head (like a helicopter), it would continue to read (0,-1,0):

[image]

I feel like this might be pretty easy, but as I am new to quaternions and don't fully understand the reference frame options for device motion, its been evading me all day.

Comment: Do you need a vector of gravity force?

Comment: Gravity vector won't work. In the first image above, the gravity vector is the same for the left (1,0,0) and right (-1,0,0) examples.

Comment: By the way, what does this have to do with quaternions?  Quaternions have *four* elements (hence the "quat" (quad) in the name).  Isn't this just the pitch roll and yaw?

Comment: This has to do with all forms of representing orientation (whether it be quaternions, Euler angles, or rotation matrices), as each of these should be able to be converted to this value that I want. pitch/yaw/roll is just a different way of representing the same information as quaternions (a worse way since it suffers from gimble lock). Quaternions are the preferred way of measuring orientation today for this and many other reasons.

Comment: Well, then you have to add magnetometer data to your gravity readings.

Comment: The theory: Normal of a plane equation should be what you want http://paulbourke.net/geometry/planeeq/ and the plane would be defined by two vectors (that you get from the accelerometer and/or CoreMotion)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. In your case we can say rotation of the device is equal to rotation of the device normal (rotation around the normal itself is just ignored like you specified it)
2. [CMAttitude](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAttitude_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which you can get via
   [CMMotionManager.deviceMotion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CMMotionManager/deviceMotion) provides the rotation 
   **relative to a reference frame**. Its properties quaternion, roation
   matrix and Euler angles are just different representations.
3. The reference frame can be specified when you start device motion updates using CMMotionManager's [startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CMMotionManager/startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:toQueue:withHandler:) method. Until iOS 4 you had to use [multiplyByInverseOfAttitude](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAttitude_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CMAttitude/multiplyByInverseOfAttitude:)

Putting this together you just have to multiply the quaternion in the *right way* with the normal vector when the device lies face up on the table. Now we need this *right way* of quaternion multiplication that represents a rotation: According to [Rotating vectors](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL:Tutorials:Using_Quaternions_to_represent_rotation#Rotating_vectors) this is done by:

**n = q * e * q'** where **q** is the quaternion delivered by CMAttitude [w, (x, y, z)], **q'** is its conjugate [w, (-x, -y, -z)] and **e** is the quaternion representation of the face up normal [0, (0, 0, 1)]. Unfortunately Apple's CMQuaternion is struct and thus you need a small helper class.

```
Quaternion e = [[Quaternion alloc] initWithValues:0 y:0 z:1 w:0];
CMQuaternion cm = deviceMotion.attitude.quaternion;
Quaternion quat = [[Quaternion alloc] initWithValues:cm.x y:cm.y z:cm.z w: cm.w];
Quaternion quatConjugate = [[Quaternion alloc] initWithValues:-cm.x y:-cm.y z:-cm.z w: cm.w];
[quat multiplyWithRight:e];
[quat multiplyWithRight:quatConjugate];
// quat.x, .y, .z contain your normal
```

Quaternion.h:

```
@interface Quaternion : NSObject {
    double w;
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
}

@property(readwrite, assign)double w;
@property(readwrite, assign)double x;
@property(readwrite, assign)double y;
@property(readwrite, assign)double z;
```

Quaternion.m:

```
- (Quaternion*) multiplyWithRight:(Quaternion*)q {
    double newW = w*q.w - x*q.x - y*q.y - z*q.z;
    double newX = w*q.x + x*q.w + y*q.z - z*q.y;
    double newY = w*q.y + y*q.w + z*q.x - x*q.z;
    double newZ = w*q.z + z*q.w + x*q.y - y*q.x;
    w = newW;
    x = newX;
    y = newY;
    z = newZ;
    // one multiplication won't denormalise but when multipling again and again 
    // we should assure that the result is normalised
    return self;
}

- (id) initWithValues:(double)w2 x:(double)x2 y:(double)y2 z:(double)z2 {
        if ((self = [super init])) {
            x = x2; y = y2; z = z2; w = w2;
        }
        return self;
}
```

I know quaternions are a bit weird at the beginning but once you have got an idea they are really brilliant. It helped me to imagine a quaternion as a rotation around the vector (x, y, z) and w is (cosine of) the angle.

If you need to do more with them take a look at [cocoamath](http://code.google.com/p/cocoamath/) open source project. The classes Quaternion and its extension QuaternionOperations are a good starting point.

For the sake of completeness, yes you can do it with matrix multiplication as well:

**n = M * e**

But I would prefer the quaternion way it saves you all the trigonometric hassle and performs better.

Comment: As I can see I have a similar question. Could you please help me with this iOS quaternions math? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25363781/iphone-rotation-quaternion-absolute-coordinates

Comment: Excellent general answer, but note that in this specific case, the x, y, z, parts of the quaternion already give the orientation that the OP was asking for.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Kay for the starting point on the solution.  Here is my implementation for anyone that needs it.  I made a couple of small tweeks to Kay's advice for my situation.  As a heads up, I'm using a landscape only presentation.  I have code that updates a variable _isLandscapeLeft to make the necessary adjustment to the direction of the vector.

Quaternion.h

```
    @interface Quaternion : NSObject{
    //double w;
    //double x;
    //double y;
    //double z;
}

@property(readwrite, assign)double w;
@property(readwrite, assign)double x;
@property(readwrite, assign)double y;
@property(readwrite, assign)double z;

- (id) initWithValues:(double)w2 x:(double)x2 y:(double)y2 z:(double)z2;
- (Quaternion*) multiplyWithRight:(Quaternion*)q;
@end
```

Quaternion.m

```
#import "Quaternion.h"

@implementation Quaternion


- (Quaternion*) multiplyWithRight:(Quaternion*)q {
    double newW = _w*q.w - _x*q.x - _y*q.y - _z*q.z;
    double newX = _w*q.x + _x*q.w + _y*q.z - _z*q.y;
    double newY = _w*q.y + _y*q.w + _z*q.x - _x*q.z;
    double newZ = _w*q.z + _z*q.w + _x*q.y - _y*q.x;
    _w = newW;
    _x = newX;
    _y = newY;
    _z = newZ;
    // one multiplication won't denormalise but when multipling again and again
    // we should assure that the result is normalised
    return self;
}

- (id) initWithValues:(double)w2 x:(double)x2 y:(double)y2 z:(double)z2 {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _x = x2; _y = y2; _z = z2; _w = w2;
    }
    return self;
}


@end
```

And my game class that uses the quaternion for shooting:

```
-(void)fireWeapon{
    ProjectileBaseClass *bullet = [[ProjectileBaseClass alloc] init];
    bullet.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 1, 0);
    [self.rootNode addChildNode:bullet];

    Quaternion *e = [[Quaternion alloc] initWithValues:0 x:0 y:0 z:1];
    CMQuaternion cm = _currentAttitude.quaternion;
    Quaternion *quat = [[Quaternion alloc] initWithValues:cm.w x:cm.x y:cm.y z:cm.z];
    Quaternion *quatConjugate = [[Quaternion alloc] initWithValues:cm.w x:-cm.x y:-cm.y z:-cm.z];
    quat = [quat multiplyWithRight:e];
    quat = [quat multiplyWithRight:quatConjugate];
    SCNVector3 directionToShoot;
    if (_isLandscapeLeft) {
        directionToShoot = SCNVector3Make(quat.y, -quat.x, -quat.z);

    }else{
        directionToShoot = SCNVector3Make(-quat.y, quat.x, -quat.z);

    }

    SCNAction *shootBullet = [SCNAction moveBy:directionToShoot duration:.1];
    [bullet runAction:[SCNAction repeatActionForever:shootBullet]];
}
```