# How to apply a filter on CMRotationMatrix using a CADisplayLink

Tags: objective-c, ios, gps, accelerometer, gyroscope

How to apply a filter on **CMRotationMatrix**? maybe kalman filter. I need fix the noise of CMRotationMatrix (transformFromCMRotationMatrix), to get a linear values of result matrix

This matrix values will be convert to XYZ, in my case I'm simulate 3D on 2D screen like that:

// Casting matrix to x, y

```
vec4f_t v;
multiplyMatrixAndVector(v, projectionCameraTransform, boxMatrix);

float x = (v[0] / v[3] + 1.0f) * 0.5f;
float y = (v[1] / v[3] + 1.0f) * 0.5f;

CGPointMake(x * self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height - (y * self.bounds.size.height));
```

**code**:

// define variable

```
mat4f_t cameraTransform;
```

// start the display link loop

```
- (void)startDisplayLink
{
    displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(onDisplayLink:)];
    [displayLink setFrameInterval:1];
    [displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}
```

// stop the display link loop

```
- (void)stopDisplayLink
{
    [displayLink invalidate];
    displayLink = nil;      
}
```

// event of display link

```
- (void)onDisplayLink:(id)sender
{
    CMDeviceMotion *d = motionManager.deviceMotion;

    if (d != nil) {
        CMRotationMatrix r = d.attitude.rotationMatrix;

        transformFromCMRotationMatrix(cameraTransform, &r);
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
```

// function trigger before [self setNeedDisplay];

```
void transformFromCMRotationMatrix(vec4f_t mout, const CMRotationMatrix *m)
{    
    mout[0] = (float)m->m11;
    mout[1] = (float)m->m21;
    mout[2] = (float)m->m31;
    mout[3] = 0.0f;

    mout[4] = (float)m->m12;
    mout[5] = (float)m->m22;
    mout[6] = (float)m->m32;
    mout[7] = 0.0f;

    mout[8] = (float)m->m13;
    mout[9] = (float)m->m23;
    mout[10] = (float)m->m33;
    mout[11] = 0.0f;

    mout[12] = 0.0f;
    mout[13] = 0.0f;
    mout[14] = 0.0f;
    mout[15] = 1.0f;
}
```

// Matrix-vector and matrix-matricx multiplication routines

```
void multiplyMatrixAndVector(vec4f_t vout, const mat4f_t m, const vec4f_t v)
{
    vout[0] = m[0]*v[0] + m[4]*v[1] + m[8]*v[2] + m[12]*v[3];
    vout[1] = m[1]*v[0] + m[5]*v[1] + m[9]*v[2] + m[13]*v[3];
    vout[2] = m[2]*v[0] + m[6]*v[1] + m[10]*v[2] + m[14]*v[3];
    vout[3] = m[3]*v[0] + m[7]*v[1] + m[11]*v[2] + m[15]*v[3];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fix the noise"? Smoothing the values or improving the signal noise ratio?

Comment: smoothing and remove signal noise, e.g the signal starts updating 11.1, 12.2, 13.3...14.4, some times jump back to 11.1 (some like that http://youtu.be/yAVCZstkORY)

Comment: Another question regarding "linear values will be converted to XYZ". Do you mean that you are finally interested in 1.) getting the [Euler Angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) out of the rotation matrix or 2.) gravity information i.e. gravity vector relative to the device or 3.) some kind of linear position detection i.e. device moves by 5 cm in direction of the X axis ?

Comment: float x = (v[0] / v[3] + 1.0f) * 0.5f;
float y = (v[1] / v[3] + 1.0f) * 0.5f;

Comment: @Kay I have add more details on question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I would distinguish between improving the signal noise ratio and smooting the signal.

**Signal Improvement**

If you really want to be better than Apple's Core Motion which has already a sensor fusion algorithm implemented, stay prepared for a long term project with an uncertain outcome. In this case you would be better off to take the raw accelerometer and gyro signals to build your own sensor fusion algorithm but you have to care about a lot of problems like drift, hardware dependency of different iPhone versions, hardware differences of the sensors within same generation, ... So my advice: try everything to avoid it.

**Smoothing**

This just means interpolating two or more signals and building kind of average. I don't know about any suitable approach to use for rotation matrices directly (maybe there is one) but you can use [quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) instead (more resources: [OpenGL Tutorial Using Quaternions to represent rotation](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL:Tutorials:Using_Quaternions_to_represent_rotation#Rotating_vectors) or [Quaternion FAQ](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/math-and-physics/the-matrix-and-quaternions-faq-r1691#Q47)).

The resulting quaternion of such an interpolation can be multiplied with your vector to get the projection similarly to the matrix way (you may look at [Finding normal vector to iOS device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827401/finding-normal-vector-to-ios-device/10836923#10836923) for more information).

Interpolation between two unit quaternions representing rotations can be accomplished with [Slerp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp). In practice you will use what is described as Geometric Slerp in Wikipedia. If you have two points in time *t1* and *t2* and the corresponding quaternions *q1* and *q2* and the angular distance *omega* between them, the formula is:

q'(q1, q2, t) = sin((1- t) * omega) / sin(omega) * q0 + sin(t * omega) / sin(omega) * q1

t should be 0.5 because you want the average between both rotations. Omega can be calculated by the dot product:

cos(omega) = q1.q2 = w1*w2 + x1*x2 + y1*y2 + z1*z2

If this approach using two quaternions still doesn't match your needs, you can repeat this by using slerp (slerp (q1, q2), slerp (q3, q4)). Some notes:

- From a performance point fo view it's not that cheap to perform three sin and one arccos call in your run loop 1/frequency times per second. Thus you should avoid using too many points
- In your case all signals are close to each other especially when using high sensor frequencies. You have to take care about angles that are very small and let 1/sin(omega) explode. In this case set sin(x) ≈ x
- Like in other filters like [low-pass filter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH4-SW11) the more points in time you use the more time delay you get. So if you have frequency f you will get about 0.5/f sec delay when using two points and 1.5/f for the double slerp.
- If something appears weird, check that your resulting quaternions are unit quaternions i.e. ||q|| = 1
- If you are running into performance issues you might have a look at [Hacking Quaternions](http://number-none.com/product/Hacking%20Quaternions/index.html)

The C++ project [pbrt](https://github.com/mmp/pbrt-v2/blob/master/src/core/quaternion.cpp#L87) at github contains a quaternion class to get some inspiration from.

Comment: What's your progress on this? Do you need any further explanation?

Comment: Maybe cocoamath's [Quaternion](http://code.google.com/p/cocoamath/source/browse/trunk/Quaternion.m) and especially the **slerp** method in  [QuaternionOperations](http://code.google.com/p/cocoamath/source/browse/trunk/QuaternionOperations.m) classes are worth to look at